# Wrapping an image around 3d object for easy 2d printing

Tags: algorithm, image, graphics, 3d, distortion

Looking for method for wrapping a 2d image around a 3d object, such as a helmet, and then unwrapping it back to 2d image to allow printing. For example, you have a photograph that you want to use to wrap a bike helmet. You do not want the image to be distorted even though it will be wrapped on complex 3d object. Once sized and positioned correctly, you need to create a 2d image that can be printed on an ink-jet printer, trimmed and then applied to the helmet.

I think there is probably overlap in these requirements and 3d textures used in games.

Comment: What material are you printing on? Are you hoping it to stretch to the curves, or expecting to cut it?

Comment: adhesive backed vinyl, cutting is fine

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you can use [warp](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/warp.html) once you've defined a [surface](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html) which can be represented in several ways, such as [this](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/trisurf.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to map an image to an arbitrary surface without distortion. I think it is not possible if "the surface does not consists of straight lines" like for example a cylinder or cone does. The same holds for you print - you cannot wrap a flat printout around an arbitrary surface except it is stretchable or you add (many) cuts until it approximately fits the surface.